# Screen Recorder not working in background in swift3 and ios 10

Tags: ios

i am working on screen Recorder application . in this application user can recode application screen with the help of reply kit. when app in active state it work perfect but when i press home button its delegate method not working in application background state. is on background mode from target application. is there any code or reference link to record screen in background then please guide me here is my screen record application code.

```
  guard recorder.isAvailable else{
        print("Cannot record the screen")
        return
    }

    recorder.delegate = self

    recorder.startRecording {[unowned self] (error) in
        guard error == nil else{
            if error!._code ==
                RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue{
                print("User declined app recording")
            }
            else if error!._code ==
                RPRecordingErrorCode.insufficientStorage.rawValue{
                print("Not enough storage to start recording")
            }
            else{
                print("Error happened = \(error!)")
            }
            return
        }

        print("Successfully started recording")
        self.startBtn.isEnabled = false

    }
```

Comment: You don't have access to the screen when your app is in suspended state.

Comment: NSdmitry you are right but there is an application which is support screen recording in background. i see the video of application using notification badge. but it is not available in app store at this time

Comment: Due to sandbox design of iOS, I don't believe any app can access screen in suspended state.

Comment: ok thanks for quick reply bro .....